# powershell - Add empty space before variable

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I am struggling to add empty space before variable. My code looks like this:

```
Write-Host "Variable description:        @var1"
Write-Host "Longer variable description: @var2"
```

I want to see:

```
Variable description:        Value1
Longer variable description: Value2
```

The result is always:

```
Variable description: Value1
Longer variable description: Value2
```

I tried add PadLeft and/or PadRight to the string and/or the variable. It worked, if I used other delimiter than "space". In the moment I use "space, it is "swallowed". The same thing happens if I use " ' ".
Can someone tell me, how to do this simple thing?

Thank you

Comment: Your code doesn't match your sample output: (a) `Write-Host` _does_ preserve the internal whitespace in a string parameter, and (b) `@var1` does _not_ get interpolated inside a double-quoted string. Please post a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your PowerShell host is messing with the white space. I can't repro that in cmd.exe or PowerShell ISE

```
$var1 = "Value1"
$var2 = "Value2"

$shortdesc = "Variable description"
$longdesc = "Longer variable description"

Write-Host $shortdesc $var1.PadLeft(35 - $shortdesc.Length)
Write-Host $longdesc $var2.PadLeft(35 - $longdesc.Length)
```

#### Output:

```
Variable description          Value1
Longer variable description   Value2
```

You can use a hash table instead or, as already mentioned, a PSObject.

```
$t = @{
    "Variable description" = $var1
    "Longer variable description" = $var2
    "A really looooooooooooooooooooooong one" = $var2
}

$t | Format-Table Key, Value
```

#### Output:

```
Key                                     Value 
---                                     ----- 
Longer variable description             Value2
A really looooooooooooooooooooooong one Value2
Variable description                    Value1
```

#### My PSVersion:

```
PS C:\> $psversiontable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14316  1000
```

Comment: I assume you meant `conhost.exe`, not `cmd.exe`; the former is the default console program that hosts both `cmd.exe` and the standard PowerShell console.

Comment: True. PowerShell host not console host.

Comment: Thank You. 
Turns out it was problem with debugger. I am using Visual studio code and it swallows the empty spaces. When I run it directly from cmd, everything is OK.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a customobject:

```
$text1 = "Variable description"
$text2 = "Longer variable description"
$var1 = "Value1"
$var2 = "Value2"

New-Object psobject -Property @{$text1=$var1;$text2=$var2} |fl
```

gives

```
Longer variable description : Value2
Variable description        : Value1
```